# beginAccept() asynchronous server issue in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I'm struggling with some piece of simple code. However, I can't get it done. I have this server, which must accept connections from multiple clients (asynchronously, obviously). So, I have:

```
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8082);

TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8082);

server = tcpListener.Server;
server.Bind(ipEndPoint);
server.Listen(4);

server.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(beginConnection), server);
```

And,

```
static void beginConnection(IAsyncResult iar)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Client connected");
    Socket s = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
    server = s.EndAccept(iar);

    server.Listen(4);
    server.BeginAccept(beginConnection, s);
}
```

Then, when I try to connect myself, the first client works OK. It just sends a message to this server, and the server sends it back to the client. The server functions as an echo. But when I try to connect another clients it doesn't work. I have also put the Console.WriteLine("Client connected"), but the server doesn't write anything.
How can I fix this problem?

I think I'm not passing the right parameter to the first BeginAccept method. Instead of server socket, I should be passing the tcpListener.

Then I would have:

```
static void beginConnection(IAsyncResult iar)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Client connected");
    TcpListener tcpListener = (TcpListener)iar.AsyncState;
    Socket s = tcpListener.Server.EndAccept(iar);

    tcpListener.Server = s; // But I would have this error

    server.Listen(2);
    server.BeginAccept(beginConnection, s);
}
```

But I would have the error that I marked it up. In the first version nothing is modified, so I think this it's the issue in the first version of the code.

Comment: This may not solve your problem, but may help. You're calling  `server.Listen(2);` in `beginConnection` It is not required there.

Comment: It is required. If I not call it, I get an error saying that I must call it. I'm confused myself on this part, because once I called it in the main method, then what's the need to call it again?

Answer (score 2):

First, you do not need the `Server` property of the `TcpListener`. You should simply call `Start()`, even without `Bind`.

Second, `EndAccept()` is also should be called at `TcpListener` and return a `TcpClient` instance which you must use for sending and receiving data.

A simple example of what I just said might be presented as:

```
{
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8082);
    listener.Start();

    AcceptClient();
}

void AcceptClient()
{ 
    listener.BeginAccept(ClientConnected, null);
}

void ClientConnected(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    TcpClient client = listener.EndAccept();
    AcceptClient();

    // Now you can send or receive data using the client variable.
}
```

Comment: listener doesn't have the Listen method!

Comment: Yes, but that's a synchronous server, and I need an asynchronous server. However, I resolved the issue. I abandoned TcpListener, and used a Socket instead.

Comment: @user2536272 Tell me how is it synchronized?!

Comment: I told you, a synchronized server uses Start. An asynchronous server uses methods with Begin(i.e. BeginAccept, BeginReceive etc)

Comment: `BeginAccept`'s synchronous counterpart is `Accept`. `Start` is used in both synchronous and asynchronous code. It does not block. It tells the socket at the OS level to start buffering new connections for you to accept.

Comment: A synchronized server uses `AcceptClient` whereas asynchronized uses the `BeginAcceptClient` and `EndAcceptClient`. Also, beginning from .NET 4.5 you can use `await AcceptClientAsync()` which is way more comfortable.